# NullPointer after deserializing JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, json.net

Im trying to fill a `List(of Person)`, `Person` being a class I created, using JSON data from a file.
I managed to extract the data from the file and save it as a String.
From this string I want to deserialize to get my `List(of Person)`.

When running, I get a NullPointer in my `Person` class, so I suspect the deserialize didn't work right.

First off my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "fname": "Lucas",
    "lname": "Films",
    "birthday": "1993-03-04T00:00:00",
  },
  {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Malkovic",
    "birthday": "1993-04-01T00:00:00",
  }
]
```

My `Person` class:

```
Public Class Person
Private _fname, _lname As String
Private _birthday As Date

Public Sub New(_fname As String, _lname As String, _birthday As Date)
    fname = _fname
    lname = _lname
    birthday = _birthday
End Sub
Property fname As String
    Get
        Return _fname
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _fname = Transform(value)
    End Set
End Property
Property lname As String
    Get
        Return _lname
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _lname = Transform(value)
    End Set
End Property
Property birthday As Date
    Get
        Return _birthday
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        Try
            _birthday = Transform(value)
        Catch
            Throw New Exception("DD.MM.YYYY")
        End Try
    End Set
End Property
Private Function Transform(inp As String) As String

    inp = inp(0).ToString().ToUpper + inp.Substring(1).ToLower
    Return inp
End Function
End Class
```

The sub which reads the JSON file:

```
Public records As New List(Of Person)

Public Sub read()
    Dim openfiledialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    openfiledialog1.Filter = "json dateien | *.json"
    If openfiledialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim jtext As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(openfiledialog1.FileName)
        records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Person))(jtext)
    End If
End Sub
```

I dont know if it's needed but here's also the sub which runs after `Button.Click` and sets everything in motion:

```
Private Sub btjson_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btjson.Click
    inst = New jsoncrud
    inst.read()
    Dim value As List(Of Person) = inst.records
    Dim frm = New showdata(value)
    Me.Visible = False
    frm.showdialog()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is valid and the deserialization is working correctly.

What produces a problem is the `Person` class constructor in combination with the `Transform` method: when a new class is created by the deserializer, it's initialized with null values. Thus, the `Transform` method will raise a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to manipulate null strings.

If you need that constructor for other reasons (the JSON deserializer doesn't need it), add a null check in the `Transform` method:

```
Private Function Transform(inp As String) As String
    If inp Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty
    Return inp(0).ToString().ToUpper & inp.Substring(1).ToLower
End Function
```

I also suggest to add some `JsonProperty` attributes, so you can assign more meaningful names to the `Person` class properties:

```
Public Class Person2
    Private _fname As String = String.Empty
    Private _lname As String = String.Empty
    Private _birthday As Date = nothing

    Public Sub New(_firstname As String, _lastname As String, _brthday As Date)
        FirstName = _firstname
        LastName = _lastname
        BirthDay = _brthday
    End Sub

    <JsonProperty("fname")>
    Property FirstName As String
        Get
            Return _fname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _fname = Transform(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("lname")>
    Property LastName As String
        Get
            Return _lname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _lname = Transform(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty("birthday")>
    Property BirthDay As Date
        Get
            Return _birthday
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            Try
                _birthday = value
            Catch
                Throw New Exception("DD.MM.YYYY")
            End Try
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function Transform(inp As String) As String
        If inp Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty
        Return inp(0).ToString().ToUpper & inp.Substring(1).ToLower
    End Function
End Class
```

Or, you could use this simplified class, since the names seem to be already formatted in *Proper Case*.

```
Public Class Person

    <JsonProperty("fname")>
    Public Property FirstName As String

    <JsonProperty("lname")>
    Public Property LastName As String

    <JsonProperty("birthday")>
    Public Property Birthday As Date
End Class
```